# Jquery Ajax Underfined

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, api

Hello I am newbie here,
I want to ask a few question about jquery
 1. How can I hide undefined in the PHP
 2. How to name inside name in the API

This is my coding
Index.php or

```
mediamonitoring.comyr.com/jquery.php
```

Or this

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Tutorial</title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/css.html'/>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>jQuery Ajax Tutorial</h1>
    <h2>Name Age</h2>
    <ul id="tutor">

    </ul>


    </body>
    </html>
    <script src='js/jquery.js'></script>
        <script src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>


    </body>
    </html>
```

And my Main.js

```
$(function(){

  var $tutor = $('#tutor');
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://rest.learncode.academy/api/johnbob/friends',
    success: function(tutor) {
      $.each(tutor,function(i,ex){//the new item is returned with an ID
        $tutor.append('<li>Name:'+ex.name+', Age '+ex.age+'</li>');
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: what do you mean by "How to name inside name in the API" ?

Comment: If u see this API http://rest.learncode.academy/api/johnbob/friends               
["","","","","","","",{"name":"Billy Bob","age":"28","id":"58dc0ffd03c59701005b04d5"},[{"name":"Best","age":"29"},{"name":"Michael","age":"34"},{"name":"Genevieve","age":"26"}], if u see my page u will say underfined. i know its underfined because no value there "". name inside name what i talking about is how to display that Best name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no 1. using if, `if(variable == null){ //hide }`

no 2. change your main.js with this

```
$(function(){
  var $tutor = $('#tutor');
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://rest.learncode.academy/api/johnbob/friends',
    success: function(tutor) {
      $.each(tutor,function(i,ex){//the new item is returned with an ID
        if(ex.name != null && ex.age != null){
            console.log(ex);
            $tutor.append('<li>Name:'+ex.name+', Age '+ex.age+'</li>');
        }        
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks you for ur reply.
Actually i dont know how to explain it, but i hope ur explanation is a answer for me.

Ok i will show u what actually i want

[link]http://mediamonitoring.comyr.com/jquery.php

this is the my site, i want to remove that undefined.

any my second actually
if u look inside api got name inside name. 
So i want to display it , i already use +ex.name[name]+
But i didnt work for me @denny-sutedja

Comment: see my edited answer. if that still not the answer you looking for, then write example result that you want.

Comment: It works.. Thank you. If i want to display my 2nd array how to do it?

Comment: create new question.

Comment: That is my 2nd question. if u see the api here http://rest.learncode.academy/api/johnbob/friends

It only display Bob
not display Best , Michael , Genevieve